# How do I pull data from a javascript populated table?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript, jquery

I am trying to pull data from my populated javascript table.  How do I pull the value from a javascript row?  I am using

```
            for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) { 
            var row = table.rows[i]; 
            //This is where I am having trouble 
               var chkboxIndicator = row.cells[0].childNodes[1]; 
               alert(chkboxIndicator);
            //
            if (chkboxIndicator == indicator && Checkbox.checked == false) { 
                table.deleteRow(i); 
                rowCount--; 
                i--; 
            } 
        }
```

which has an alert message of "undefined".  I tried .value and .text as well and no progress.  How do I get the text from the childNodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block of code that I was missing was the following

```
var row = table.rows.item(i).cells;
var cellLength = row.length;
var cellVal = row.item(5).innerHTML;
```

Thanks for leading me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `chkboxIndicator`  is not `null`?

If it is null it will alert as undefined.

Try

```
for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) 
{ 
    var row = table.rows[i]; 
    // Add null check for row
    if (row != null)
    {
        //This is where I am having trouble 

        // Add null check for cell
        if (row.cells[0] != null)
        {
            var chkboxIndicator = row.cells[0].childNodes[1];

            // Added null check for chkboxIndicator
            if (chkboxIndicator != null)
            {
                alert(chkboxIndicator);


                if (chkboxIndicator == indicator && Checkbox.checked == false) 
                { 
                    table.deleteRow(i); 
                    rowCount--; 
                    i--; 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert('chkboxIndicator is NULL');
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The childNodes value is what is null.  How do I get the text/value from this?

Comment: What does your html look like?  You can get the text from the cell by either calling innerText or innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your DOM actually looks like.

I suspect your problem is that childNodes[1] could be a text node.

You probably want to use a selector on the cell instead, such as:

```
$(row.cells[0]).find("input[type='checkbox']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're purportedly using jQuery, why not use it to get your checkboxes and simplify your life?

```
$("#mytableid tr").each(function() {
    // find the checkbox (assuming you have only one; if not, use :eq(n))
    var $checkbox = $("input:checkbox", this);
    // if it's checked, delete this row
    if ($checkbox.is(":checked"))
        $(this).remove();
});
```

There are crazier ways to do it, but I thought that example would be illustrative. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be fast too, use jOrder (http://github.com/danstocker/jorder).

Create a jOrder table with your data. Make sure to have a field 'checked' in it with true or false values, and put an index on that column and the ID:

```
var table = jOrder(data)
    .index('id', ['ID'])
    .index('checked', ['checked'], { grouped: true });
```

Then, you can rebuild your grid with the unchecked rows removed using `table.where([{ 'checked': true }])` as the source.

But first, populate your grid with the data from the jOrder table. Use `table.flat()` to obtain the flat table.
When you build the grid, bind the record IDs to the checkboxes e.g. by `$('#elem').data()`. When a checkbox gets (un)checked, update the 'checked' value in the table:

```
var before = table.where([{ 'ID': 5 }])[0];
var after = table.where([{ 'ID': 5 }])[0];
after.checked = true;
table.update(before, after);
```

Note that you shouldn't do this for each item on an "(un)check all" event though. In that case just simply pass on `table.flat()` or set the 'checked' values in the buffer returned by it, and then issue a `table.reindex()` and THEN call `table.where(...)`.

Comment: Looks very interesting! Do you have some sample code or something on how to work with your jOrder and HTML tables? To keep them in sync and all?

Comment: There's no fast way worked out just yet, but there will be sometime soon. For now, you have to re-build the table even on the slightest changes. Keep an eye on the jOrder blog at http://jorder.wordpress.com, I'll post news, plans, and sample code as often as I can.